# A bug in merge sort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Can you guys please help me with this code. I know this is basic but I am now really obsessed with it. I am trying to implement a very simple version of mergesort, but the output is all wrong. Please try to fix this code instead of writing a completely new one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void merge_them(int a[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i=l, j=m+1;
    int final[r-l+1];
    int p=0;
        
    for(int k=0; k<=r-l+1; k++)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[j])
        {
            final[p]=a[i];
            i++;
            p++;    
        }
            
        else if(a[i]>=a[j])
        {
            final[p]=a[j];
            j++;
            p++;
        } 
    }
        
    j=0;
    for( i=l; i<r+1; i++)
    {
        a[i]=final[j];
        j++;
    }
}
    
void merge(int a[], int l, int r)
{ 
    if(l<r)
    {   
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        merge(a,l,m);
        merge(a,m+1,r);
        merge_them(a,l,m,r);   
    }    
}
    
int main()
{
    int a[10] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
       
    merge(a,0,9);
       
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);  
}
```

UPDATE: This was not a homework. I was just revisiting some sorting algos based on recursion and tried to implement Merge sort. Anyway, I switched to while loop and used a more precise condition check, which led to correct sorted outputs.

Comment: "*but the output is all wrong.*" Please be more specific. Describe some inputs, the output of the program, and expected output.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Add lots of unit tests, and then attach a debugger to a failing one :-)

Comment: Unrelated, `final` is a poor choice for a variable name, it is a [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

Comment: This looks to be homework. We are not here for that.
What have you tried ? What did not work spefically ? Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @M.A Actually, as far as I can tell, this is c code :p

Comment: `int final[r-l+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Are you being taught this is valid C++ code?

Comment: I think you're learning c, not c++. I've retagged the question.

Comment: It's actually much easier to avoid off-by-one errors if you stick to the conventional half-open intervals. (That's one of the reasons for their being conventional.)

Comment: When j is 10, `if(a[i]<a[j])` is accessing an array element out of bounds.  You should use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: @M.A Not that I recommend using it anyway, although not that it matters because this is C - but `final` is only a reserved word in C++ in specific circumstances, and it's fine to use for other purposes elsewhere: "`final` is an identifier with a special meaning when used in a member function declaration or class head. In other contexts it is not reserved and may be used to name objects and functions."--[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) The same is true for `override` too.

Comment: @underscore_d When i made the comment, the question was tagged C++ and not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually three bugs:

- The condition `k<=r-l+1` in the `for` statement is wrong and it will have it do one more loop. It should be `k<r-l+1` (`<` should be used instead of `<=`) like the condition `i<r+1` used later.
- The condition `a[i]<a[j]` is wrong because it isn't checking if the parts are used up. It should be `j > r || (i <= m && a[i]<a[j])`.
- `if(a[i]>=a[j])` should be removed because if you don't take an element from one part, you will obviously take from another part.